# Issues with the heighmap

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

We are having couple of issues with the heightmap modelling.!

a) Using an attached grayscale image ([image description](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/13690992339782541.png)) Gazebo generates some inexplicable peaks in one of the corners ([image description](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/1369099274312890.png)).  Always in the same corner, independent of how I draw the texture. We are using an attached model.sdf [C:\fakepath\model.sdf](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/13690994601679407.sdf) file from the tutorial to include the heightmap.

b) Images resolution including 33x33 and less cause Gazebo to segfault upon starting it.

c) When including very large heightmaps (e.g. 48 48 0.5) Gazebo becomes super slow (e.g. 0.01 real time). Is this a known behaviour?

d) is it possible to get rid of the extrusion of the heightmap-based model under the ground plane? See attached pic to see what I mean. [image description](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/13690994989939951.png)

We are on the 1.5  version, `catkin_groovy` branch: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/6c1ec8a7598efa8574b908522386eb13d9d8427f/?at=catkin_groovy.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2895/issues-with-the-heighmap/) by [dejanpan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/30/dejanpan/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 60 on 2013-05-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Enrique Fernández](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/398/enrique-fern%C3%A1ndez/) on 2013-06-20**:
same problem here, with 1.5 as well.
Also tried 1.8.6, and in that case it crashes.
Both versions are 32bit, by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm transitioning this to a gazebo [issue](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/746/heightmap-feature-requests-and-issues).

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0